I want this string "12 1 4" as integer outputs 12 1 4
I have been trying to get a string of numbers as integer outputs.
For example string "12 1 4" as space separated integer outputs 12 1 4
I wrote this code.
used stoi() and substr operation.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string s = "12 8 9 7 8";
  // vector<int> ar;
  int size = s.size();
  cout << size << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int a = 0;
    if (s[i] != ' ') {
      a = stoi(s.substr(i, 1));
      cout << a << ' ';
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}

10
1 2 8 9 7 8
This gives me all integers separated.
But when I tried
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string s = "12 8 9 7 8";
  // vector<int> ar;
  int size = s.size();
  cout << size << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int a;
    if (s[i] != ' ') {
      a = 10 * a + stoi(s.substr(i, 1));
      cout << a << ' ';
    } else {
      a=0;
      continue;
    }
  }
}

The output was
10
-2077343247 701404012 8 9 7 8 
why? What am I missing here?
I just started learning c++, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

In the second case, a is uninitialized so a = 10 *a is undefined behavior. There may be other problems too with the code.

If you would read the numbers from a file or from std::cin, would you know how to do that? Then you might like to know about std::istringstream which is an input stream (like std::cin) for strings. That would make the parsing and extraction of the numbers in the string much simpler.

a = stoi(s.substr(i, 1)); – honestly? A substring of length 1 is just a single character, that character you can retrieve via s[i] – and standard guarantees digits to be encoded consecutively, thus you can simply subtract '0' to get the digit value: a = s[i] - '0';… If you want to be on the safe side you might check with isdigit in advance or simply have unsigned int a = 0 and check if the calculated digit value is <= 9 (otherwise the character is not a decimal digit, either coming after the digits or, then converting a negative value to a huge positive one, before).

Your code, in contrast, does not check for non-digits at all.

string s = "12 8 9 7 8"; std::istringstream strm(s); int num; while (strm >> num) std::cout << num << " "; -- Compare that simple code to what you wrote.
